# Symfony set arbitrary data into anonymous visitor session

Tags: session-cookies, symfony, symfony-2.7

*Using Symfony 3.0.7*

### Simply said:

I'm unable to set and retrieve arbitrary datas into session for an anonymous user.

### In other words ..

I usually retrieve datas from session object, inside any controller with those few lines:

```
public function dummyAction(Request $request)
{
    # …
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $my_datas = $session->get('my_key');
    # …
```

Until today this was needed (and worked) on urls that stands behind a firewall configured the standard way, meaning with *login* and *login_check* keys along with *user providers*, etc.

***BUT***

Now, I need a new firewall to guard a new area: **"*/api/.+*"**.
This area must be stateless but a special uniq URI **"*/api/signup*"** has to allow sessions.
And so I created the following firewalls

```
firewalls:
    apisignup:
        pattern: api/signup
        anonymous: ~
    api:
        pattern: /api/
        provider: usr
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt: ~
```

All I need is to persist a single scalar value (a captcha solution) into session when visitor hits

```
GET http://192.168.0.5/app_dev.php/en/api/signup
```

then, on POST to that same url, I need to retrieve the value.

**Notes**
Currently whether I hit this url through GET or POST the server response always contains a "set-cookie" header, as if the browser simply drops this command and do not pass cookie along on next request.

I tested using the following snippets:

```
### SERVER SIDE
/**
 * @Route( "/signup", name="api_signup")
 * @Method( {"GET","POST"} )
 */
public function signupAction( Request $request )
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    if ( $request->isMethod('POST') ) {
        $datas = $request->request->all();
        return new JsonResponse([
            'received' => $datas['captcha']
            ,'captcha' => var_export($session->get('captcha'), true)
        ]);
    }
    $session->set('captcha','foobar');
    return new JsonResponse(['challenge' => 'foobar']);
}

### CLIENT SIDE
$.ajax({
    url:'http://192.168.0.100/app_dev.php/en/api/signup'
    ,method: 'get'
    ,success : function(datas){
        // datas.challenge && $('#captcha').html(datas.challenge) &&
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://192.168.0.100/app_dev.php/en/api/signup'
            ,method: 'post'
            ,data: {
                captcha: 'foobar' // prompt("Captcha ?")
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

POST `JsonResponse` "captcha" value always contains **null**.

Any Idea of what ("I'm missing" | "could lead to this behaviour") ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you are issuing requests from another domain.
In this case remind that CORS require:

1. Server side, `Access-control-allow_credentials` **header** has to be set to true
2. Client side, `withCredentials` **xhr property** has to be set to true

Then, your XHTTP Request will push any available set cookies for that domain with the request. Make sure to set a proper restriction policy in order to lower risks of [CSRF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery)

Comment: You are right, I figured out that part of the javascript involved in requests interchange which takes care of appending `withCredentials` property was commented out. Thank you.